# Explain the tenses 'has been' and 'emerges'

Tags: tense

My freelancer who is a native speaker wrote these two sentences. I already asked him to explain his use of the tenses, but he has no ability to explain at all. I don't understand his use of 'has been' for the past period from 1970 to 2020? Do you think this is correct? Shouldn't 'had been' be used? Is the second sentence about predictions? I don't understand the use of the present simple 'emerges' for predictions. Can you explain?

> Overall, there **has been** a steady increase in the percentage of the
> population residing in cities in all four countries **from 1970 to 2020**.
> Malaysia **emerges** as the frontrunner with the highest proportion of
> city residents compared to the others.

[image]

Comment: It's fine. There are no errors. "has been" is the present perfect, and we use this tense to link past events to what is happening now - in this particular example it is clear that the increases are still happeining now, so the present perfect is appropriate here.  "Emerges" is not being used for a prediction. It's simply being used to state a general fact. This is a common use of the simple present tense in English.

Comment: I agree with Billy Kerr.  We only use **had been** to talk about something in the past *before* something else in the past.  For example, you might say "Mexico had been the front-runner for many years, but in 1965 it was overtaken by Brazil."

Comment: Thank you both. Is the past simple correct? There **was** a steady increase in the percentage of the population residing in cities in all four countries from 1970 to 2020. So by using 'emerges', the second sentence is about the entire period from 1970 and 2040?

Comment: @newbieforever - There is **nothing** wrong with the sentence as written. There is no need to change anything. The grammar is correct.

Comment: @BillyKerr, thank you but can you tell me if the second sentence about Malaysia is about the entire period from 1970 and 2040? I don't know what period the freelancer is talking about.

Comment: No. I;ve already told you what it means in my first comment.  I'm not going to repeat it.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I'm aware that you said it's simply being used to state a general fact. But the graph is not about a general fact. It's about the period from 1970 to 2040. I really don't understand.

Comment: The simple present is about now. Something which is true in the present (a general fact that is true today) right now in 2023.   Malaysia "emerges" as the front runner. This is  a fact.  It is apparent that Malaysia **is** the front runner.

Comment: The statistics shown in the graph tell us that Malaysia is the country with the greatest proportion of its people living in cities. That information 'comes out of' the statistics.

Comment: The freelancer is wrong. You're right. It should read "*... there **was**...Malasia **emerged**...*".